# Are there a tools that can help to treat files as tables in a database?

Tags: python, database, linux, csv, ipython

I have csv files and would like to treat them as tables of a database. Of course I can transform these files into tables. But it would be nice to have a possibility to do it directly in the command line (in a way like `grep`, `head`, `tail`, `sort` and `awk` are used).

For example I would like to `select` a particular column of a file (given by its name), or select rows `where` certain columns have certain values, or `order by` one of the columns.

Comment: `awk` is your friend. If you provide some input and desired output you will be astonished how much magic can be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you tagged this with python and ipython, I assume you'd like to see what it would be like to do this from an ipython prompt. So, here's a trivial CSV file people.csv:

```
first,last,age
John,Smith,20
Jane,Smith,19
Frank,Jones,30
```

Now, here's an ipython session using it:

```
In [1]: import csv
In [2]: from operator import *
In [3]: with open('foo.csv') as f: people = list(csv.DictReader(f))
In [4]: [p['age'] for p in sorted(people, key=itemgetter('first')) if p['last'] == 'Smith']
Out[4]: ['19', '20']
```

It takes one line to read a CSV file into memory as a list of dicts.

Given that, you can run list comprehensions on it.

So, the `p['age']` selects a column by name; the `sorted(people, itemgetter('first'))` orders by another column, and the `if p['last'] == 'Smith'` is a where clause.

That second one is a bit clunky, but we can fix that:

```
In [5]: def orderby(table, column): return sorted(table, key=itemgetter(column))
In [6]: [p['age'] for p in orderby(people, 'first') if p['last'] == 'Smith']
Out[6]: ['19', '20']
```

---

You can even do `group by` clauses with a little help from [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), although here you'll definitely want to define helper functions both for groupby and for the aggregates to apply to groups, and I think it still might be pushing the limits a bit…

```
In [7]: from itertools import *
In [8]: def ilen(iterable): return sum(1 for _ in iterable)
In [9]: def group(table, column): return groupby(table, itemgetter(column))
In [10]: [(k, ilen(g)) for k, g in group(people, 'last')]
Out[10]: [('Smith', 2), ('Jones', 1)]
In [11]: def glen(kg): return kg[0], sum(1 for _ in kg[1])
In [12]: [glen(g) for g in group(people, 'last')]
Out[12]: [('Smith', 2), ('Jones', 1)]
In [13]: def gsum(kg, column): return kg[0], sum(int(x[column]) for x in kg[1])
In [14]: [gsum(g, 'age') for g in group(people, 'last')]
Out[14]: [('Smith', 39), ('Jones', 30)]
```

---

However, there are a few things to keep in mind:

- It requires reading the whole thing into memory.
- There are no "indexes". With a database, selecting the 20 Smiths out of 100000 people only needs log(100000)+20 steps; with a list, it needs 100000 steps.
- You have to order the operations appropriately. When you want to order, then filter rows, then filter columns (as in the example above), everything is easy; if you want a different order (especially if you want to order or filter by columns you aren't selecting), you may need to write more complex comprehensions, while with a database there's no problem at all.

---

Keep in mind that it's only about 5 lines of code to convert a CSV file to a sqlite table. So, I think you'd be better off with a script that just runs your 5-line Python program and dumps you into a sqlite command line.

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged this with 'python', python's 'pandas' module provides a DataFrame object that provides the functionality that you seem to want here. Use pandas.read_csv() to read in the CSV file. A quick primer on DataFrames is provided here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe